# Query a remote neo4j server via Java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, remote-server

Can anybody provide some example code of how to connect and query a remote neo4j server via Java?  I'm not looking for an embedded neo4j server implementation.

Here is an attempt to get this working:

```
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphDatabaseService neo4j = new RestGraphDatabase("neo4jurl");
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(neo4j);
        String myCypher = "MATCH n WHERE n.symptom = 'Xanthelasma'";
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(myCypher);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
```

This results in this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/ClientFilter
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.createRestRequest(ExecutingRestAPI.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.<init>(ExecutingRestAPI.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.<init>(RestAPIFacade.java:294)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.<init>(RestGraphDatabase.java:51)
    at mapreduce.NetworkAnalysis.main(NetworkAnalysis.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

I have also tried to implement this using jersey:

```
String baseURI = new String("neo4jurl");
String payload = "db/data/node/5/relationships/all/CO_SYM";
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI + payload);
System.out.println(target.getUri());
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request();
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

This does return data from neo4j, but it is in html format and I would like to utilize the cypher query language.

Comment: Please post your attempt to solve the problem, some research, something. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Thanks Lord, I have updated the question.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your edit will greatly assist the next person to look at this question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that!

Use

```
CypherQueryEngine cypher = new RestCypherQueryEngine(restGraphDB.getRestAPI());
cypher.query(statement, params);
```

For your second example, your base-uri is wrong. Also you have to add `content-type` and `accept` headers to be `application/json`

Comment: could you please explain why he shouldn't use 'RestGraphDatabase'? As this is the approach I read on other fora.